# appending to multiple elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list

Suppose you have a list `foo` containing some elements.

```
foo <- list()
foo[1:3] <- "a"
foo
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

# [[2]]
# [1] "a"

# [[3]]
# [1] "a"
```

I would like to efficiently grow the list by both appending to existing elements and adding additional elements. For example adding "b" to elements 2:5, as simply as possible, preferably using `foo[2:5]<-`.

Desired output

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "b"

# [[3]]
# [1] "a" "b"

# [[4]]
# [1] "b"

# [[5]]
# [1] "b"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh this indeed works:

```
foo[2:5] <- lapply(foo[2:5], c, "b")
```

The `c` is the concatenation function.